# taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is deprecated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Until now, the way to get the url from file on Storage in Firebase, I used to do this 
`taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl`,  but nowadays is deprecated, which method I should use?

[image]

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/UploadTask.TaskSnapshot.html#getDownloadUrl()

Answer (score 19):

As Doug says, you will need to run it inside a Task

Here is a hint of how you need to implement it

```
final StorageReference ref = storageRef.child("your_REF");
uploadTask = ref.putFile(file);

    Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw task.getException();
            }

            // Continue with the task to get the download URL
            return ref.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                String downloadURL = downloadUri.toString();
            } else {
                // Handle failures
                // ...
            }
        }
    });
```

For more information about how to implement it, you can check this github question that was opened 7 days after I answered this https://github.com/udacity/and-nd-firebase/issues/41

Comment: What is the type of `uploadTask`? I am stuck. The code does not execute for me.

Comment: Except the storage reference has to be final. How to accomplish this without it being final?

Comment: declare it globally

Comment: @mfgabriel92 uploadTask is the type of UploadTask , so you need to declare it this way UploadTask uploadTask;

Comment: The declaration of the urlTask is never used?

Comment: for more info Robert, you can please check this github post https://github.com/udacity/and-nd-firebase/issues/41

Comment: This is the correc answer. The firebase documentation also uses the continueWithTask method. See the section "Get a download URL": https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/upload-files#get_a_download_url

Answer (score 10):

Use this implementation for your uploadTask and will work. :)

```
uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Task<Uri> firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                firebaseUri.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

                        String url = uri.toString();
                        Log.e("TAG:", "the url is: " + url);

                        String ref = yourStorageReference.getName();
                        Log.e("TAG:", "the ref is: " + ref);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 8):

This code work for me.

You can try.

```
package br.com.amptec.firebaseapp;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.UUID;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    private FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    private Button btnUpload;
    private ImageView imgPhoto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnUpload = findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        imgPhoto = findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);

        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                imgPhoto.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imgPhoto.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = imgPhoto.getDrawingCache();
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                String fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

                StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                StorageReference images = storageReference.child("images");
                StorageReference imageRef = images.child(fileName + ".jpeg");

                UploadTask uploadTask = imageRef.putBytes(imageBytes);

                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(MainActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Error: " +
                                e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        //Uri url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Task<Uri> uri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                        while(!uri.isComplete());
                        Uri url = uri.getResult();

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Success, download URL " +
                                url.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i("FBApp1 URL ", url.toString());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: This is neither an acceptable question nor even article. pls if you have a problem mention it. otherwise, express the question as a question and answer procedure. for example, you ask something and you answer to your own question

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [StorageReference.getDownloadUrl()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl()).  Please note that it returns a Task, so you will have to remember to treat it asynchronously like you do any other Task.

Comment: What about StorageReference.getDownloadUrl().toString()? It seems to work by returning the url

Comment: @FlorianWalther It doesn't return a URL.  Take a good look at the string - it doesn't even begin with "http".  It returns an internalized string representation of the task object, which is entirely not helpful here.

Comment: Weird because I tested it in my app and it worked as before

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create an instance of StorageReference first (here in this code snippet, it is storageRef)  

StorageReference filepath = storageRef.child("images.jpg");

 //If file exist in storage this works.
 filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                                // downloadurl will be the resulted answer
                             }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the code below:

```
Task<Uri> downUrl=taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
Log.i("url:",downUrl.getResult().toString());
```

Comment: it doesn't return a url

Answer (score 0):

You wont get the download url of image now using

ImageUrl = taskSnapshot.**getDownloadUrl**().toString();
this method is deprecated.

Instead you can use the below method

```
uniqueId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
ur_firebase_reference = storageReference.child("user_photos/" + uniqueId);

Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(mphotofile.getAbsolutePath()));
UploadTask uploadTask = ur_firebase_reference.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return ur_firebase_reference.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            System.out.println("Upload " + downloadUri);
            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Successfully uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (downloadUri != null) {

                String photoStringLink = downloadUri.toString(); //YOU WILL GET THE DOWNLOAD URL HERE !!!!
                System.out.println("Upload " + photoStringLink);

            }

        } else {
            // Handle failures
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

You can track the progress of uploading by adding Progress listeners,

```
uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
            System.out.println("Upload is " + progress + "% done");
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "Upload is " + progress + "% done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }).addOnPausedListener(new OnPausedListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onPaused(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            System.out.println("Upload is paused");
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            // Handle successful uploads on complete
            // ...
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just use a Task instead of ref.putFile(uriImage)
                  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener()
Nowadays, firebase references suggest using Uploadtask objects**

I've done it like this:

```
UploadTask uploadTask;
        uploadTask = storageReferenceProfilePic.putFile(uriProfileImage );

        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw task.getException();
                }

                // Continue with the task to get the download URL

                return storageReferenceProfilePic.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    progressBarImageUploading.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    profileImageUrl = downloadUri.toString();
                    ins.setText(profileImageUrl);
                } else {
                    // Handle failures
                    // ...
                }
            }
        });
```

Notice these lines in the above code:

```
Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
profileImageUrl = downloadUri.toString();
```

Now profileImageUrl contains something like "http://adressofimage" which is the url to acess the image

Now you're free to use the String profileImageUrl however you wish. For e.g., load the url into an ImageView using Glide or Fresco libraries.

Answer (score 0):

```
Task<Uri> task = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();
task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
       @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
              String photoLink = uri.toString();
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use taskSnapshot.getTask() instead of taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() works fine for me.