# Retrieving images from Firebase does not work?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Retrieving images from Firebase does not work?
Hi I am working on upload and retrieve images from Firebase.
But `taskSnapshot.getDownlaodUrl` is currently deprecated.
So I use the alternative as answered in this question

[taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467814/tasksnapshot-getdownloadurl-is-deprecated)

but none of these alternatives work for me.

```
 @Override
    public void onActivityResult( int requestCode,int resultcode,Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultcode,data);
        if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT&&resultcode==RESULT_OK)
        {  mbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Uri uri=data.getData();
       final   StorageReference fileupload=mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
       fileupload.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(){
            @Override
             public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
              mbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Succesfully Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Task<Uri> firebaseUri = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                Picasso.get().load(firebaseUri.getResult.toString()).into(image);

            }
                }
       );
```

This is my code for upload and retrive the data.

**It gives me error for Task is not yet Complete**

and when i try another alternative

```
filepath.getDownloadUrl().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                String downloadUrl = task.getResult().toString();
                              Picasso.get().load(downloadUrl).into(image);
                             }
 });
```

**It gives me error of Object does not exit**
I am making a child reference for Photos and try to retrive the image.
Can anyone solve whats wrong in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final   StorageReference fileupload=mStorage.child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
UploadTask uploadTask = fileupload.putFile(file);

Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }
        return ref.getDownloadUrl();

    }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                Picasso.get().load(downloadUri.toString()).into(image);

            } else {
                 // Handle failures
            }
       }
});
```

Comment: missing retrun statement after throw statement

Comment: Thanks it worked for me.I earlier tried the same code but i think the Retrieving
 of image was taking time i thought it  is  not Retrieving.Can you please do the same for me by checking the tick on Left side of Question.

Comment: You can give star so i can earn my student badge.