# Unity- How to get the download URL once an image is uploaded to firebase storage?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-storage

I'm using the basic unity firebase storage documentation provided by firebase.

[image: Picture provided by firebase]

after implementing the codes i get an error saying

> 'StorageMetadata.DownloadUrl' is obsolete: 'StorageMetadata.DownloadUrl is deprecated. Please use StorageReference.GetDownloadUrlAsync() instead' (CS0619) [Assembly-CSharp]

after that i have changed the code as

```
string download_url = storage_ref.Child("ss.jpg").GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString();
```

in my code

```
images_ref.PutFileAsync(local_file).ContinueWith((Task<StorageMetadata> task) =>
{
    if(task.IsFaulted || task.IsCanceled)
    {
        Debug.Log(task.Exception.ToString());
        status.text = "Uo-oh, an error occurred!";
    }
    else
    {
        // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
        Firebase.Storage.StorageMetadata metadata = task.Result;
        Debug.Log("Finished uploading...");

        //string download_url = metadata.DownloadUrl.ToString(); // This shows error

        //Changed as
        string download_url = storage_ref.Child("ss.jpg").GetDownloadUrlAsync().ToString();
        Debug.Log("download url = " + download_url);
    }
});
```

but when use this it does not returns a string of that URL

It returns :

> download url = System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Uri]

I need to get the string value of downloadURL of the image once it is uploaded. Please help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because async returns a task, you need the result of the task.

Comment: yes, thank you.. But how do i get the url as a string ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50467814/tasksnapshot-getdownloadurl-is-deprecated)

Comment: The linked isnt necessarily firebased but its exactly the same problem and question

Comment: @BugFinder the question isn't primarily about `DownloadUrl()` but [`GetDownloadUrlAsync`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/storage-reference#getdownloadurlasync) though

Comment: @derHugo and that question answers with how to use the getdownloadurlasync, with examples, so was exactly the same hence I consider it a dup

Comment: to me they seem more about [`getDownloadUrl`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#public-taskuri-getdownloadurl-) which isn't exactly the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like most of the firebase methods [`GetDownloadUrlAsync()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/firebase/storage/storage-reference#getdownloadurlasync) as the name already says is `async` and returns a `Task<Uri>`.

just as before you should use [`ContinueWith()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/unity/class/system/threading/tasks/task.html#continuewith)

```
storage_ref.Child("ss.jpg").GetDownloadUrlAsync().ContinueWith((Task<Uri> uriTask) => 
{
    string download_url = uriTask.Result.ToString();
    Debug.Log(download_url);
});
```

where `result` will be of type [`Uri`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.uri)

Comment: I still get the same result as System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Uri] in the console. I need the string value of this result which is the URL to download the Img.

Comment: sorry you have to use the `Result` of the task .. renamed it to make it clearer

Comment: Thank you, saved another hour of mine!!