# how to get a clickable link to pdf file uploaded to firebase storage

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am unable to use android app to get a clickable link to pdf file uploaded to firebase storage with firebase storage version 19. (`com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1`).

addOnSuccessListener snippet:

```
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @SuppressWarnings("VisibleForTests")
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textViewStatus.setText(R.string.file_uplod_success_msg);
        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: FileName is:" + FileName);
        String url = tasksnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString();
        Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: URL :"+ url);
        Upload upload = new Upload(editTextFilename.getText().toString(), url);
        mDatabaseReference.child(mDatabaseReference.push().getKey()).setValue(upload);
    }
})
```

The url returned in my debug log: `Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess: URL :"+ url);` is `onSuccess: URL: com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@f9fc59b` which is not a clickable link.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55440618/2855810

Comment: Thanks so much. it  worked perfectly